# Crear nuevo array ordenado a partir array compuesto de otro

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas noches compañeros , estoy tratando de crear un array (N) a partir de otro (A) porque ese array "A" tiene digamos varios resultados de varias estructuras que me interesan entonces lo que quiero es crear un nuevo array pero con cada estructura con sus respectivos items . Por ejemplo:

Mi array original sería algo así:

```
data = [
0: {COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_MEDIDOR", ID: "01", TEXT: "Bueno"}
1: {COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_MEDIDOR", ID: "02", TEXT: "Malo"}
2: {COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_REGULADOR", ID: "01", TEXT: "No se puede regular"}
3: {COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_REGULADOR", ID: "02", TEXT: "Corrosión"}
4: {COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", ID: "01", TEXT: "Prueba de resistencia y hermerticidad"}
5: {COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", ID: "02", TEXT: "Con equipo detector"}
6: {COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", ID: "03", TEXT: "Solución jabonosa"}
]
```

Como debería y quedar ordenar el arreglo nuevo:

```
nuevo_arr = [
{titulo: "ESTADO_MEDIDOR", items: [{ID: "01", TEXT: "Bueno"}
    {ID: "02", TEXT: "Malo"}]},
{titulo: "ESTADO_REGULADOR", items: [{ID: "01", TEXT: "No se puede regular"}
    {ID: "02", TEXT: "Corrosión"}]},
{titulo: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", items:{{ID: "01", TEXT: "Prueba de resistencia y hermerticidad"}
    {ID: "02", TEXT: "Con equipo detector"}
    {ID: "03", TEXT: "Solución jabonosa"}}}
]
```

Yo intenté hacer algo así, pero mi problema es que no se por que para mis primeros dos array no los crea en mi nuevo array y al momento de finalizar un grupo de items el siguiente grupo no lo toma en cuenta, quizas viendo lo que hice se entienda mejor:

```js
_setData : function(data) {
            var flag = "";
            var arrFinal = [];
            var entidad = [];
            data.map( function(dato, index) {
                if ( dato.COMBO_BOX !== flag && index === 0) {
                    flag = dato.COMBO_BOX;
                    var dat = {};
                    dat.ID = dato.ID;
                    dat.TEXT = dato.TEXT;
                    entidad.push(dat);
                } else {
                    if ( dato.COMBO_BOX == flag ) {
                        dat = {};
                        dat.ID = dato.ID;
                        dat.TEXT = dato.TEXT;
                        entidad.push(dat);
                    } else {
                        var entidadFinal = [];
                        var info = {};
                        info.title = dato.COMBO_BOX;
                        info.items = entidad;
                        arrFinal.push(info);
                        flag = dato.COMBO_BOX;
                        entidad = [];
                    }
                }
            });
        },
```

Esto es lo que obtengo con mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede que para uds sea algo fácil pero ahorita estoy algo saturado y he intentado haciendo varios cambios a mi código pero aún no veo la solución

Se me acaba de ocurrir recorrerlo con un for y luego dentro otro for , intentaré y actualizo mi pregunta pero si alguien sabe una forma mas prolija que me pueda guiar lo agradecería mucho

ACTUALIZACION

Logré hacerlo con lo que había comentado del for con un map y un empujón de internet me ayudo pero sinceramente no entiendo muy bien como funciona (la última línea), si alguien sabe por favor hágamelo saber:

```
_setData : function(data) {
            var entidad = [];
            var items = [];
            for ( var i in data ) {
                var row = {};
                row.name = data[i].COMBO_BOX;
                data.map( function(dato, index) {
                    if ( dato.COMBO_BOX === data[i].COMBO_BOX ) {
                        var dat = {};
                        dat.ID = dato.ID;
                        dat.TEXT = dato.TEXT;
                        items.push(dat);
                    }
                });
                row.items = items; 
                entidad.push(row);
                items = [];
            }
            const uniqueObjects = [...new Map(entidad.map(item => [item])).values()]

        },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Te digo como hacerlo con menos lineas de codigo y si te puedo ayudar a aclarar conceptos mejor.

Lo que hace el metodo `.map` de los arreglos es devolverte un nuevo arreglo con la misma cantidad de elementos pero "transformados" cada uno de los elementos pasa por una funcion y sale un nuevo valor en su lugar, pero si tienes 10 elementos te van a devolver tambien 10 elementos. En tu caso quieres terminar con menos elementos de los que partes

Un ejemplo muy comun con `.map` es tomar un arreglo de numeros y obtener el doble

```javascript
const numeros = [1,2,3,4];
const duplicados = numeros.map(x => x * 2); // [2,4,6,8]

// o sin arrow function:

const duplicados = numeros.map(function (x) {
  return x * 2 
}
```

Una forma facil de pensarlo es visualizar como tienes el arreglo y como te gustaria tenerlo y solo te queda pasarle una funcion que haga el truco, en este caso una funcion que tome un numero y devuelva el doble te sirve para terminar con un arreglo nuevo que tiene todos los elementos que tenias al principio pero * 2.

Pero en realidad esto no es lo que estas necesitando, en tu codigo hiciste uso de map pero como si fuera un `.forEach` en para ir metiendo cosas a un nuevo arreglo, ahora te propongo otra forma de hacerlo con `reduce`.

`.reduce` es un metodo parecido a map, tambien esta disponible en los arreglos y la diferencia esta en que en vez de devolver la misma cantidad de elementos "transformados", va a devolver una salida "unica". Le vas a dar un acumulador y por cada uno de los elementos de tu iterable vas a decidir como afecta ese elemento a tu acumulador.

`.reduce` es un poquito mas dificil de entender que `.map`. Te dejo un ejemplo generico con un arreglo de comidas y luego la solucion a tu problema. Te pongo numeros en los comentarios para que sepas en que orden leerlos.

```js
comidas = [
  { categoria: "fruta", nombre: "banana" },
  { categoria: "fruta", nombre: "manzana" },
  { categoria: "lacteos", nombre: "yogurt" },
  { categoria: "lacteos", nombre: "leche" },
];

function transformData(data) {
  return data.reduce((acumulador, alimento) => {
    // 2. En cada iteracion nos preguntamos si ya existe un item en nuestro arreglo que represente a esta categoria de comidas en este caso
    categoria = acumulador.find(
      (item) => item.categoria === alimento.categoria
    );
    // 3. Si ya teniamos una categoria de comidas, solo agregamos este alimento a esa categoria
    if (categoria) {
      categoria.comidas.push(alimento.nombre);
    } else {
      // 4. Si no existia esa categoria entonces pusheamos un objeto con esa categoria y un arreglo de comidas con la primera de esas comidas, la proxima comida de esta categoria va a disparar el flujo del IF porque ya va a existir una categoria en el arreglo.
      acumulador.push({
        categoria: alimento.categoria,
        comidas: [alimento.nombre],
      });
    }
    return acumulador;
  }, []); // 1. Nuestro acumulador comienza como un arreglo vacio
}

const comidaTransformada = transformData(comidas);
console.log(comidaTransformada);
```

Y la solucion ideal para tu problema seria esta:

```js
dataOriginal = [
  { COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_MEDIDOR", ID: "01", TEXT: "Bueno" },
  { COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_MEDIDOR", ID: "02", TEXT: "Malo" },
  { COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_REGULADOR", ID: "01", TEXT: "No se puede regular" },
  { COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_REGULADOR", ID: "02", TEXT: "Corrosión" },
  {
    COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION",
    ID: "01",
    TEXT: "Prueba de resistencia y hermerticidad",
  },
  { COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", ID: "02", TEXT: "Con equipo detector" },
  { COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", ID: "03", TEXT: "Solución jabonosa" },
];

function transformData(data) {
  return data.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    item = acc.find((item) => item.titulo === elem.COMBO_BOX);
    if (item) {
      item.items.push({ ID: elem.ID, TEXT: elem.TEXT });
    } else {
      acc.push({
        titulo: elem.COMBO_BOX,
        items: [{ ID: elem.ID, TEXT: elem.TEXT }],
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const nuevaData = transformData(dataOriginal);
console.log(nuevaData);
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: Amigo que gran explicación si hay varias cosas que aprendí de todo lo que me dijiste y  seguiré aprendiendo pero de antemano muchísimas gracias y gran explicación!

Answer (score 0):

te dejo una solución alternativa al map que quizás sea un poco mas sencilla de leer:

```
data = [
    {COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_MEDIDOR", ID: "01", TEXT: "Bueno"},
    {COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_MEDIDOR", ID: "02", TEXT: "Malo"},
    {COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_REGULADOR", ID: "01", TEXT: "No se puede regular"},
    {COMBO_BOX: "ESTADO_REGULADOR", ID: "02", TEXT: "Corrosión"},
    {COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", ID: "01", TEXT: "Prueba de resistencia y hermerticidad"},
    {COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", ID: "02", TEXT: "Con equipo detector"},
    {COMBO_BOX: "PRUEBA_DETECCION", ID: "03", TEXT: "Solución jabonosa"}
];

var res = [];

data.forEach(function(element) {
    var oldElement = res.find(x => x.titulo == element.COMBO_BOX);

    if(oldElement)
        oldElement.items.push({ ID: element.ID, TEXT: element.TEXT });
    else
        res.push({
            titulo: element.COMBO_BOX,
            items: [{ ID: element.ID, TEXT: element.TEXT }]
        });
});

console.log(res);
```

y dará como respuesta:

```
Array[Object {
    titulo: "ESTADO_MEDIDOR",
    items: Array[Object {
        ID: "01",
        TEXT: "Bueno"
    }, Object {
        ID: "02",
        TEXT: "Malo"
    }]
}, Object {
    titulo: "ESTADO_REGULADOR",
    items: Array[Object {
        ID: "01",
        TEXT: "No se puede regular"
    }, Object {
        ID: "02",
        TEXT: "Corrosión"
    }]
}, Object {
    titulo: "PRUEBA_DETECCION",
    items: Array[Object {
        ID: "01",
        TEXT: "Prueba de resistencia y hermerticidad"
    }, Object {
        ID: "02",
        TEXT: "Con equipo detector"
    }, Object {
        ID: "03",
        TEXT: "Solución jabonosa"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias  por su ayuda si es como más fácil de leer, se aprecia!